# How to add multiple conditions in a while-loop

Tags: python, while-loop, conditional-statements

I'm creating a text based game with multiple stats you have to keep up, such as stamina, health, etc. and I am having trouble with what happens if they go below `0`. I know a while-loop would work I could do:

```
life = 1
while(life > 0):
    print("You are alive!")
    print("Oh no! You got shot! -1 Life")
    life-1
print("You are dead! Game Over!")
```

But I don't know how to do that with multiple conditions such as stamina, hunger, strength etc.

Comment: what happens if you have life, strength and stamina but hunger reaches 0 or less?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine them into a single test using [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min):

```
while min(life, health, stamina) > 0:
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `0` evaluates to `False` in Python, you can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
while all((life, stamina, hunger, strength)):
```

This will test if all of the names are not equal to zero.

If however you need to test if all of the names are *greater* than zero (meaning, they could become negative), you can add in a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
while all(x > 0 for x in (life, stamina, hunger, strength)):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `and` and `or`. For example:

```
while (life > 0) and (health > 0) and (stamina > 0):
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put `if` statements into the while loop that check those stats at the start of each iteration.  That way you can handle each event individually.

```
life = 1
while(life > 0):
    if stamina < 1:
        print "out of stamina"
        break
    if hunger < 1:
        print "You died of hunger"
        break
    print("You are alive!")
    print("Oh no! You got shot! -1 Life")
    life-1
print("You are dead! Game Over!")
```